# При клике на картинку отправить письмо

Tags: html

Как при клике на картинку отправить письмо? Есть ли простое решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
<img alt="alt text" src="picture.png">
</a>
```

При клике на картинку откроется почтовый клиент.

Answer (score 1):

Если это форма, то элементу button можно прописать свойство background-image.

```
button{
background-image: url(относительный путь к картинке);
}
```